# Using cURL instead of file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

My web host does not support file_get_contents for security reasons but does support the use of cURL. Can anyone tell me now I would convert this short code using curl? I've been trying for days with no luck so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/b2b4a1ad0a889006/geolookup 
/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
$temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'}; 
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php pretty much sums usage up.

Comment: why you dont use Weather Underground api  ?

Comment: $ch=curl_init("http://api.wunderground.com/api/b2b4a1ad0a889006/geolookup/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
$responce =  json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use socket

```
<?php
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://api.wunderground.com:80", $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "GET /api/b2b4a1ad0a889006/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: api.wunderground.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo json_decode(fgets($fp));
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```